# Music note class

Tags: python, music

A class for notes calculation.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from string import ascii_uppercase


class Notes:
    notes = ascii_uppercase[:7]
    notes_number = range(7)
    notes_dict = dict(zip(notes, notes_number))
    numbers_dict = dict(zip(notes_number, notes))

    def __init__(self, _note):
        if not _note in Notes.notes:
            raise Exception("Not a valid note")
        self.note = _note
        self.note_number = Notes.notes_dict[self.note]

    def add(self, n):
        if not n in range(8):
            raise Exception("Not a valid number")

        old_number = Notes.notes_dict[self.note]
        new_number = (old_number + n) % 7
        return Notes.numbers_dict[new_number]

    def minus(self, n):
        if not n in range(8):
            raise Exception("Not a valid number")

        old_number = Notes.notes_dict[self.note]
        new_number = (old_number - n) % 7
        return Notes.numbers_dict[new_number]
```

Test:

```
x = Notes("G")
x.add(7)
```

Comment: What about sharps/flats and different octaves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `__init__` assigns `self.note_number`, but the other functions don't use it, instead they look up the number from the `dict`. Choose one approach and eliminate the other.
- Checking the range of `n` and raising the exception in `add` and `minus` is not necessary, because the computation has a valid result for all numbers.
- `add` and `minus` are almost the same. One function that allows a negative argument would suffice. If you want to keep `minus` implement it simply as `return self.add(-n)`

Answer (score 5):

I recommend to rename the class from `Notes` to `Note`,
as plural suggests a collection of notes,
when in fact your implementation is for individual notes.

---

[PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests to use `x not in items` instead of `not x in items`,
so instead of this:

> ```
> if not n in range(8):
> ```

This is the recommended way:

```
if n not in range(8):
```

---

`notes` and `notes_number` are not great names,
and the second could be derived from the first, like this:

```
class Note:
    valid_note_letters = ascii_uppercase[:7]
    valid_note_numbers = range(len(valid_note_letters))
```

---

This is not efficient:

> ```
>     if not n in range(8):
> ```

In the worst case,
it will iterate over all 8 elements of the range.
It would be better this way:

```
if not 0 <= n < 8:
```

This is a simple range check with precisely 2 comparisons.

---

A custom `__str__` implementation would be user-friendly:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.note
```

Comment: Python 3 doesn't need `object`; all classes are new-style by default

Comment: Wow, thanks @jonrsharpe for that, good to know

Answer (score 3):

Your code is full of `7` and `8`, numbers like that are called [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)
and should be avoided. Instead use a constant.

Comment: Named constants are certainly appropriate for things which could be changed without rendering a program meaningless. To my eye, however, they are not always appropriate in cases where they aren't just used as numbers but also form part of the structure of a program or its algorithms. Within the context of musical note processing, it would take less thinking for me to recognize the numerical literals 7 and 12 as being more recognizable the number of letter names per octave and half-steps per octave, respectively, than for me to recognize LetterNamesPerOctave and HalfStepsPerOctave.

Comment: A concern I would have using a named constant for LetterNamesPerOctave is that such usage might imply that code could be easily adapted to something like German note names (German uses letters A-H, but doesn't use eight note letters per octave; a C major scale in German would be C-D-E-F-G-A-H-C, while F major would be F-G-A-B-C-D-E-F). If the relationship between letter names and chromatic note numbers is baked into the program structure, numeric literals would simply be a part of that.