# Music note class - v2

Tags: python, music

Version 2 of [Music note class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71863/music-note-class-in-python)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from string import ascii_uppercase
from string import ascii_lowercase


class Notes:
    octave_number = 7
    low_notes = ascii_uppercase[:octave_number]
    high_notes = ascii_lowercase[:octave_number]
    notes = low_notes + high_notes
    notes_number = range(octave_number * 2)
    notes_dict = dict(zip(notes, notes_number))
    numbers_dict = dict(zip(notes_number, notes))

    def __init__(self, _note):
        if not _note in Notes.notes:
            raise Exception("Not a valid note")
        self.note = _note
        self.note_number = Notes.notes_dict[self.note]

    def add(self, n):
        if (self.note in Notes.high_notes) and (n > 0):
            raise Exception("You can only add to low notes (ABCDEFG)")
        if (self.note in Notes.low_notes) and (n < 0):
            raise Exception("You can only subtract from notes (abcdefg)")
        if(abs(n) > Notes.octave_number):
            raise Exception("Maximum amount of increase or decrease is %d" % Notes.octave_number)


        new_number = self.note_number + n
        return Notes(Notes.numbers_dict[new_number])
```

Test:

```
x = Notes("A")
x.add(7).note
x = Notes("b")
x.add(-6).note
```

Changes:

- Removed `minus` method
- Expanded notes to two octaves
- `add` now returns a Notes object

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be aware of Python's "magic methods" to implement class behaviours, including numerical methods like `__add__` and `__sub__`. This allows you to write e.g. `note3 = note1 + note2`, rather than `note3 = note1.add(note2)`. There are also methods for display, including `__repr__`, so you can easily view the instance. Additionally:

- the class name should be singular, as this only holds one note, and constants should be `UPPERCASE`;
- it's easier to handle either uppercase *or* lowercase and convert all input accordingly;
- you can access class attributes via `self` too, which makes inheritance easier;
- you check `note` in `__init__`, but there's nothing to protect it afterwards; and
- `number` could be calculated based on `note` as required, rather than stored as duplicate information.

Here's an alternative implementation with those ideas in.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from string import ascii_uppercase

class Note:

    NOTE_COUNT = 7
    NUMBERS = dict(enumerate(ascii_uppercase[:NOTE_COUNT]))
    NOTES = {v: k for k, v in NUMBERS.items()}

    def __init__(self, note=None, number=None):
        if note is not None and note.upper() in self.NOTES:
            note = note.upper()
        elif number is not None and number in self.NUMBERS:
            note = self.NUMBERS[number]
        else:
            raise Exception("Not a valid note")
        self._note = note 

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Note({._note!r})".format(self)

    @property
    def number(self):
        return self.NOTES[self._note]

    @property
    def note(self):
        return self._note

    @note.setter
    def note(self, new_note):
        new_note = new_note.upper()
        if new_note not in self.NOTES:
            raise Exception("Not a valid note")
        self._note = new_note

    def __add__(self, other):
        try:
            num = other.number
        except AttributeError:
            num = other
        return Note(number=((self.number+num)%self.NOTE_COUNT))

    def __sub__(self, other):
        try:
            num = other.number
        except AttributeError:
            num = other
        return Note(number=((self.number-num)%self.NOTE_COUNT))
```

In use:

```
>>> B = Note("B")
>>> C = Note("C")
>>> B + C
Note('D') # not sure this addition makes sense, but it works!
>>> B.note = "X"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 1, in <module>
    B.note = "X"
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 30, in note
    raise Exception("Not a valid note")
Exception: Not a valid note
>>> B.number
1
```

Now all you need is octaves and accidentals! You should also add some [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) explaining what the class does and how to use it.

Comment: If you overload binary operators, you should return `NotImplemented` in ambiguous cases. [See this discussion.](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/2odotz/is_there_a_quick_and_easy_way_to_include_lt_gt_ge/cmmf1eh?context=10000) Consider also the different behaviour of `x = []; x = x + ()` and `x = []; x += ()`. In this vein I strongly disagree with overloading `__add__` to support addition of notes with numbers, but would be fine with `__iadd__` doing so.

Comment: @Veedrac if anything, I think that in this case adding `Note` instances makes *less* sense than adding a number to a `Note`! Interesting point though, I will take it on board. Do you have a more canonical source than something you also asserted elsewhere?